# Signing and verifying data with Java won't work

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, pki

I created a rsa key pair (plus a self-signed certificate) with openssl by using the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privado-ssl.pem -out certificado-ssl.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

The name of the generated files and its contents are:

privado-ssl.pem:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA45TtNcik6ToMf6pgfcZhnYx8XlQKWuYLF0KyVNJIHn+H1Wp9
Tyhbjw9xSsZOPw4RiwgUdidmdH0GlTvm0AxieYjT2gZDFoYH+O9Zd2+KMpOFWhFU
(etc, etc...)
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

certificado-ssl.pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEmDCCA4CgAwIBAgIJAOMPP5KhPi+WMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGOMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJQRTENMAsGA1UECBMETGltYTENMAsGA1UEBxMETGltYTETMBEGA1UEChMK
Tm92YXRyb25pYzEMMAoGA1UECxMDQ0FUMRgwFgYDVQQDEw9EYW5pZWwgQ2FsZGVy
(etc, etc ...)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Since I'm using java.security.* classes to sign and verify signature, I transformed privado-ssl.pem (my private key) to PKSC8 format and DER enconding by using:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in privado-ssl.pem -out privado-ssl-pkcs8-der.pem -nocrypt
```

But, when using said classes to verify a signature I get false when verifying signature (but no exception).

This is the way I get the private key from the private key file (as an byte array):

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
KeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
return keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

And the certificate:

```
InputStream certificateInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateBytes);
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
return certificateFactory.generateCertificates(certificateInputStream).get(0);
```

For signing and verifying, I'm using SHA1withRSA algorithm with no provider.

What can I possibly be doing wrong? Please, if you need more information just let me know. Desperate here :)

Comment: *For signing and verifying, I'm using SHA1withRSA algorithm with no provider.* - Please show this in detail.

Comment: What you posted looks good, and 'no exception' is better. My only immediate thought is confirm the data you `.update` for verify is byte for byte identical to that used when signing, and the signature you try to verify is byte for byte identical to that returned from signing. If that doesn't help, reduce your code to the minimum that shows the problem (MCVE) and post that. PS: the last openssl where `req -newkey` writes legacy format was 0.9.8, which is now end-of-life at least upstream. If you depend on this openssl for anything important, look into upgrading when you can.

Comment: PPS: probably you don't *specify* a provider; there always *is* a provider.

Comment: Can you please provide all of your Java code?